# How to pick a random word from text file (array) using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, random, text-files

How can I pick a random word from a file of comma-separated words?

Comment: @Jesse you have posted a link to this same page.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = file_get_contents('the_file.txt'); //Take the contents from the file to the variable
$result = explode(',',$var); //Split it by ','
echo = $result[array_rand($result)]; //Return a random entry from the array.
```

Comment: 'echo = $result[array_rand($result)];'  ?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo explode(',',file_get_contents('file.txt'))[rand(0,99)];
```

That is it in the least amount of code.