# Python: Lists and Random. How to pick random numbers between 0 and [number of strings in the list]?

Tags: python, list, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I randomly select an item from a list using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

I am trying to create a string that uses 3 different lists for 3 different words:

```
print (word1[random.randint(0, X )],
       "the",
       word2[random.randint(0, X)],
       word3[random.randint(0, X)])
```

`word1`,`word2` and `word3` are different lists.

The `X` in randint is the amount of strings in the respective lists.

So, could anybody help me out and tell me how i write this code correctly?

```
word1[random.randint(0, [amount of strings in list "word1"])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making an unwarranted assumption that you need to pick such a random number. The random number is not the thing that you want; you want a random element of the string.

To make a random choice from a sequence, use `random.choice`.

```
print(random.choice(word1), "the", random.choice(word2), random.choice(word3))
```

Comment: Woowh. Thanks mate... ive been wanting to do this for several weeks now, but i guess my teacher is a dumbass XD forcing us to learn stuff that has too much math (vectors n stuff) and not even explaining anything that has to do with programming.

Comment: Your teacher probably honestly believes that getting you to think in these "mathematical" terms will actually improve your programming instincts and ability to break down a programming problem logically. This misconception is frighteningly common.

Comment: @ChaosPointDK - you can learn the library by reading the tutorials at python.org.

Answer (score 0):

`randrange`: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange

Answer (score 0):

`len()` gets the length of something. Using `len(word1)` would get the number of items in the list. What I assume you want to do is pick a random word from the list. `random` actually has its own module to do that. You would use `random.choice(word1)` to get a random item from `word1`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple : `word1[randomint(0, len(word1)-1)]`