# randomly selecting items from an array python

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I randomly select an item from a list using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

I have two arrays pool_list_X , pool_list_Y. Both have a numpy array as element in the list.
So basically

```
pool_list_x[0] = [1 2 3 4] # a multidimensional numpy array.
```

and every element of pool_list_x has corresponding element in pool_list_y

```
which is to say, that pool_list_x[i] corresponds to pool_list_y[i]
```

Now. if I have to randomly select 10 elements from list_x (and hence the corresponding elements to list_y). how do i do this.
I can think of a very naive way.. randomly generate numbers. and stuff.. but that is not very efficient.. what is the pythonic way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Did you think of looking at the standard library? Maybe googling this or searching stackoverflow?

Comment: Like i said, i know the naive way.. but in this case.. i would have to generate a random number and check for collisions in order to make sure that same number is not generated twice and 10 is just an example.. i want to generate like 100k random numbers.. this method wont suffice.

Comment: Yes, it is true that before you ask any question on stackoverflow, you should perform a minimum of research which includes looking for existing answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually an exact duplicate. *This* question asks how to select multiple elements, while the proposed duplicate is about selecting *one* element.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you one hundred percent, but I think using `zip` and `random.sample` might work:

```
import random
random.sample(zip(list_a,list_b), 10)
```

Some short explanations:

- `zip` will create a list of pairs, i.e. it ensures that you pick corresponding elements - if you pick one, you automatically get the other (`Zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]) = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]`)
- `random.sample(l,n)` randomly selects `n`  elements from a list `l`

Answer (score 5):

There is a function allowing you to get the random element of the given sequence:

```
import random
my_choice = random.choice(my_sequence)
```

For details see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice).