# How to randomly select items in a set

Tags: python, random, python-3.x, set

For my homework assignment I am supposed to randomly select items in a list. so far I have this code,

```
import random

room = range(0, 365)
r = random.choice(room)

mySet = set(r)
```

However, when I attempt to run the program, it says that " 'int' is no iterable".

I was wondering how I can fix this problem?

Comment: you should include the error you get

Comment: I answered your question, but I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Just fyi it may not be a good idea to post a link to your assignment in the future TA's and profs use SO too.. and the philosophy on posting homework is very split

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I randomly select an item from a list using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

Answer (score 5):

[`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#sets.Set) requires an iterable (a list or tuple are iterables) as its argument, where you’ve supplied an integer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to choose random items (with fixed size) from a set:

```
list = random.sample(your_set, size);
```

or if you want to choose random items with random size:

```
size = random.randint(0, your_set_size):
list = random.sample(your_set, size):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
However, when I attempt to run the program, it says that " 'int' is no iterable".

I was wondering how I can fix this problem?
```

Use `randint`:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(0, 360)
86
>>> var = randint(0, 360)
>>> isinstance(var, int)
True
```

`set` is actually a type in python, an object like `list` or `dict`. Thus, when you pass in an `int` from `random.choice`, it gives you an error, because it needs a `list`, something that you can loop through is an `iterable` object. So, for example:

```
>>> set([1,3,4,5,2])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Will work, but what you tried to do is this:

```
>>> set(1)  # 1 is used as a number here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If you wish to create a random list, you can do something like this:

```
>>> [randint(0, 360) for _ in xrange(10)]
[234, 122, 294, 71, 204, 360, 359, 318, 273, 212]
```

The above code creates 10 random integers for you to work with. If you want a `set`, you can just use the `set` function to get one, but I think its important for you to understand *what* `set` is and what it does. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: While using `randint` is clearly better than `random.choice(range(...))`, you should try to explain the OP gets the error message.

Comment: @joaquin Well, added information about sets, but not going to spoon feed the information.

Comment: Note you are not answering to a single OP but to a community of people that will search also for this answer in the future. The tag homework was removed time ago. Answers should be useful for all the whole community. More complete answers (not neccesarily the first) are expected to be the most upvoted ones in SO. It is right your answer doesnt deserves a downvote. Still your answer is incomplete, imho. Anyway I give back to you my downvote (it was set before your edits) :-)

Comment: @joaquin Well, there are _tonnes_ of answers just like this one. In fact, this question has nothing unique to offer. That is the reason why the question has not been answered to the fullest.

Answer (score 2):

Your set also just has a single value in it so you only have one thing to iterate over. `random.choice` returns only a single element in the sequence in this case an int. This isn't the cause of the python error (int is not iterable as sneeu says) but will lead to a different result than what you are looking for. `random.sample` is probably a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of assigment, you needn't initialize set with something. You should only add elements in set in each test and check size of set and number of insertions.

That why init should be like this:
        import random

```
    room = range(0, 365)
    mySet = set()
```

P.S. Your code below initialization isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because you are creating a set object from an int. 
A set should be created from an iterable (like a list) not a single object:

So instead of this :
mySet = set(r)
You should do this :
mySet = set([r])

Why don't you follow the Notes from your homework ?

> Notes
>   For each test, you should use Random.randint to pick a number
>   between 0 and 365 to use that represents a birthday

randint() returns a random integer without having to create a list, which is what is required with the function you are using :choice()