# How to make python choose randomly between multiple strings?

Tags: python, random

How to make python choose randomly between multiple strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I randomly select an item from a list using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

Comment: Paste your code into your question, don't take a screenshot and post that on an external site...

Comment: Heya, welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally it's Good Form to include your code here. It's ok to include a link to a fiddle like you have here - but we also want to see your code... don't forget that programmers are leery of clicking on links to external sites in case they are spam or phishing attempts... ;) Also - that fiddle will go away sometime, and we want Stack overflow to be eternal... and the only way that will happen is if you put your code here.

Comment: Real code so we an copy/paste - not a screenshot :)

Comment: And *especially* not a screenshot too small to read :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add them all to a list, import random, then call the choice method like so:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: hello = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'bonjour', 'hola', 'salaam']
In [3]: random.choice(hello)
Out[3]: 'bonjour'
```

Comment: No problem, apparently other users hated my comment though. Have fun with python! It's a great language.

Answer (score -2):

`random.choice()` is your friend.