# Python 3 - Using randint without some values

Tags: python-3.x

How can i hold back some values while using choice

```
>>> x
['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 10, 9]

>>> choice(x),choice(x),choice(x),choice(x),choice(x)
(10, 'Jack', 9, 'King', 10)
```

Now i need to ask the user to hold back some values. If he chooses Jack for ex. I need to keep Jack aside and chose any four values from x.
something like -

```
('Jack',10, 9, 'Queen', 'Ace')
```

Also, Can i do the same with randint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(random.choice(foo))
```

Example from :: 
[How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

Hopefully this is what you need (+code to maintain the list contents)