# How to generate list of random integers, but only using specified integers? (Python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, integer

This question could be generalized to randomly creating a list of size n, containing pre-specified integers (assuming a uniform distribution).  Hopefully it would look like the following:

Perhaps the syntax would look something like

```
randList([list of integers], size)
```

which could then produce something along the lines of:

```
randList([1,-1], 7)
>>> [1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1] #(random)
```

or

```
randList([2,3,4], 10)
>>> [4,3,4,2,2,4,2,3,4,3] #(random)
```

I am a bit new to python and everywhere I look it is always returning a range of values between a low and a high, and not specific values.  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need `random.choice`.

Comment: Then make a loop and append each time?

Comment: A list comprehension would be more idiomatic than a for loop - `[random.choice(seq) for _ in range(10)]` or something, where `seq` is your list of candidate values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vals = [random.choice(integers) for _ in range(num_ints)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fully working example. All you need to do is replace the value of `choices` with the list of numbers you want to select from and replace `range(10)` with `range(number_of_items_i_want)`

```
import random
choices = list(range(10))
random_sample = [random.choice(choices) for _ in range(10)]
```

If you want this as a function so that you can reuse it, this would be an easy way to do it:

```
import random
def random_list(choices, size):
    return [random.choice(choices) for _ in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `random.choice`, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python) for a discussion.

However, even if you could only do values within a range:

> I am a bit new to python and everywhere I look it is always returning
>   a range of values between a low and a high

...You could still do what you want here, just assume the low/high limits to be 0 -> the size of your list, and then with each random int generated in that range, take the number *at that index*.