# How can I create a list of players in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, random

I have a list of players with the following attributes 
 - assetId maxBid minPrice maxPrice

How can I create a list in Python and pick one player at random an apply it to a search function.

I am looking to accomplish something like this :

```
players = []
players.append(13732, 8000, 9300, 9400) #John Terry
players.append(165580, 2400, 3000, 3100) #Diego Alves
for player in players:
    items = fut.searchAuctions('player', 
                               assetId=player.assetId,
                               max_buy=player.maxBid)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't run. It helps a lot if you have can indicate the *actual* problem where you are stuck? For example, do you have problems running the above code? Or do you not know how to get a random element from a list (hint: look at the random module)?

Comment: This is quite a good link for choosing a random item from a list:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python

Comment: You should use http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe for this purpose as more convenient a clear way of managing datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a player class:

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, assetId, maxBid, minPrice, maxPrice):
    self.assetId = assetId
    self.maxBid = maxBid
    self.minPrice = minPrice
    self.maxPrice = maxPrice
```

this way you can create new objects with `player = Player(13732, 8000, 9300,9400)`
Your list would the be created with

```
players = []
players.append(Player(13732, 8000, 9300,9400))
players.append(Player(165580, 2400, 3000, 3100))
```

to select a player randomly you can do

```
import random
randomPlayer = random.choice(players)
```

now you can use `randomPlayer` and its attributes e.g. `randomPlayer.assetId` and pass it to your search

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

player = random.choice(players)

player.search()...
```