# Python randomly delegating values from one list to another

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
  a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

  b_list = ['1', '2', '3']
```

What is the best way to randomly delegate list values from b_list to great tuples in a new list:

```
   c_list = [('a','1'), ('b','3'), ('c','1')]
```

Comment: I think that question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python

Comment: You don't use `2` from b_list, is that expected or do you want to use all values?

Comment: Sounds like a home work, did you have tried anything so far to figure it out?

Comment: @Andy this is expected, as I want it to randomly delegate values from b_list to a_list.  c_list could well be a1,b1,c1 or a2, b2,c3 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b_list = ['1', '2', '3']
print [(a,random.choice(b_list)) for a in a_list]
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', '3'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '3')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Shuffling the lists and `zip` them would get your job done.

```
import random

a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

b_list = ['1', '2', '3']

random.shuffle(a_list)
random.shuffle(b_list)

c_list = zip(a_list, b_list)
```

Or if you don't want the one to one mapping then you may also use :

```
import random

a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

b_list = ['1', '2', '3']

c_list = [(i, random.choice(b_list)) for i in a_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

As in your output I could see repeated values. Use below.

Without repetition:

```
random.shuffle(b_list)
print zip(a_list, b_list)
```

With repetition:

```
print [ (i,random.choice(b_list)) for i in a_list ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from functools import partial

a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

b_list = ['1', '2', '3']

r= partial(random.choice,b_list)

list(zip(a_list,[r(),r(),r()]))

[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '2')]
```