# Random choice function

Tags: python, random

I am making a game using pygame based on the game war. I am getting an error when running the code for splitting my deck in the main loop (it is in its own file). The error says:

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The deck splitting file looks like this:

```
import Deck
from random import *
deck = Deck.deck
playerDeck = []
AIDeck = []

def splitDeck():
    player_deck_count = 26

    while player_deck_count > 0:

        transfer_card = (choice(deck))

        playerDeck.append(transfer_card)
        deck.remove(transfer_card)

        player_deck_count -= 1

    AIDeck = deck
    shuffle(playerDeck)
    shuffle(AIDeck)


print "Player deck length:" + str(len(playerDeck))
print "AI deck length:" + str(len(AIDeck))
print "Deck length:" + str(len(deck))
```

The Deck file looks like this:

```
deck = [
    '2_c',
    '2_d',
    '2_h',
    '2_s',
```

I get that is has to do with the sequence (list is empty) but there is obviously still 26 cards in the original deck. I have tried changing when the while player_deck_count loop stops but with no luck. Thanks for the help in advance

P.S. just comment if you want the main loop.

Comment: use `return random.choice(seq)`. See this [SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)

Comment: `shuffle(deck);playerDeck=deck[:26];AIDeck=deck[26:]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are relying on the function to set the value of AIDeck. When you attempt to set

```
AIDeck = deck
```

you are moving the reference of `AIDeck` to the reference of `deck`. When the function returns, `AIDeck` is restored to its original definition, which was the empty list. If you are doing `choice(AIDeck)` anywhere in your file, it is probably the cause of your error.

Comment: I am not doing `choice(AIDeck)`

Comment: In any case, even after calling `splitDeck()`, `AIDeck` will be the empty deck.