# python identificare random syntax in text

Tags: python

i have this input text file bio.txt

```
Enter for a chance to {win|earn|gain|obtain|succeed|acquire|get} 
1⃣Click {Link|Url|Link up|Site|Web link} Below️
2⃣Enter Name
3⃣Do the submit(inside optin {put|have|positioned|set|placed|apply|insert|locate|situate|put|save|stick|know|keep} {shipping|delivery|shipment} adress)
```

need locate syntax like this {win|earn|gain|obtain|succeed|acquire|get} and return random word, example : win

how i can locate this in python started from my code :

```
input = open('bio.txt', 'r').read()
```

Comment: I don't think you've actually done anything to achieve what you requested.

Comment: Have a look at the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  you need to read the text file into a string; find the pattern "{([a-z|]+)}" using regex, split them by "|" to make a list as random words. It could be achieved as the following:

```
import re, random
seed = []
matches = re.findall('{([a-z|]+)}', open('bio.txt', 'r').read())
[seed.extend(i.split('|')) for i in matches]
input = random.choice(seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for your pattern (`"\{.*\}"` according to your example) with regex on each line.
Then once you found it, simply split the match by a separator (`"|"` according to your example).
finally return randomly an element of the list.

Regular expression doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Python's string common operation doc (including `split` ) https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Get a random element of a list : [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)