# How do I pick x random elements from a list, for x > len(list)?

Tags: python, list, random

I need to pick random elements from a list.
And the number of random elements is larger than the length of the list (so I will have duplicates).
Therefore I can't use random.sample(), because the sample can't be larger than the population.
Does anyone have a solution?

For example:

lst = [1,2,3,4]

How can I pick 5 random elements from this list, like [1,4,3,1,2]?

Comment: Pick a single random element 5 times?

Comment: Use `random.choice` in a loop / list comprehension / generator expression. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, that you want to pick at random from a population, this should do the trick:

```
import random

list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

random_elements = [random.choice(list) for n in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
lst = [1,2,3,4]
choices = numpy.random.choice(lst, size=5, replace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) in a loop or list comprehension to return random elements from your input list.

Here's a list comprehension example:

```
from random import choice

lst =  [10, 20, 30, 40]

num = 5
seq = [choice(lst) for _ in range(num)]
print(seq)
```

**typical output**

```
[20, 40, 10, 30, 20]
```

And here's the same thing using a "traditional `for` loop:

```
from random import choice

lst =  [10, 20, 30, 40]

num = 5
seq = []
for _ in range(num):
    seq.append(choice(lst))
print(seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need no third-party modules.  Just use a list comprehension:

```
choices = [random.choice(lst) for _ in range(5)]
```

Another way that is a little shorter, but not as efficient is this:

```
choices = list(map(random.choice, [lst]*5))
```

In Python2, `map()` already returns a list, so you could do:

```
choices = map(random.choice, [lst]*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer involves the [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) function and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

I suggest also to put the magic inside a function whose name makes explicit what it does.

```
import random

def pick_n_samples_from_list(n, l):
    return [random.choice(l) for n in range(n)]

n = 5
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(pick_n_samples_from_list(n, lst))
>[3, 1, 4, 4, 1]
```