# Trying to print random lines from a file but it prints one character at a time

Tags: python

This is probably something so simple. I'm scripting something to print random lines from a file but it prints one character at a time. Here is the code.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import random, time

filename = open('test.txt')
line = random.choice(filename.readlines())
filename.close()

for line in line:
print line
```

Any help is definitely appreciated. I'm a beginner so it honestly is probably something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `random.choice` will return a string. And in effect you are iterating over a string. What you should do is call `split()` after you call `random.choice` so you end up with a list of words instead of a string. Then your iteration will work as expected.

Also, you really should not iterate like this:

```
for line in line
```

Change your iterator:

```
for word in line
```

Also, it would be good practice to get used to using [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) when handling files. e.g.:

```
with open(some_file) as f:
    # do file actions here
```

So, your final solution would look like:

```
import random

with open('new_file.txt') as f:
    line = random.choice(f.readlines()).split()

for word in line:
    print(word)
```

Comment: You're the best! Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to instruct the OP to use `with` for the file instead of `open`/`close` directly.

Comment: @jpmc26 didn't forget, was just trying to focus on OP immediate issue, but it's a good suggestion. Thanks. Added.

Comment: I went ahead and made these changes like you suggested. I am trying to make it loop infinitely but it does not seem like it's working.

while 1 == 1:
 Code
 time.sleep(10)

but it wont loop

Comment: Why are you trying to make it run infinitely? Based on what you are trying to do, the corrections made, it should be all you need?

Comment: I'm really just trying to practice what I have learned online but this just won't work. There's no real use for this, just me learning :)

Comment: @NMetallic Understood. But if you are wanting to use a while loop, then you need to use a break statement. You have to set a condition to break it on. Putting a condition in your while is dangerous. If you want to practice with a `while`, then do `while True`, and inside your while loop have a condition, that when met will `break`.

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` will return only on element at a time, you have to use `shuffle` instead:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import random, time

filename = open('test.txt')
lines = filename.readlines()
filename.close()

random.shuffle(lines)

for line in lines:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things, first thing is readability:

```
for line in line
    print line #which line do you mean?
```

Now,

```
line = random.choice(filename.readlines())
```

Will just give you a random line in the file, it won't give you all the lines in a random order.

You can shuffle the array with a simple call

```
import random

filename = open('new_file.txt')

lines = filename.readlines()

random.shuffle(lines)

for line in lines:
    print line
```

You can also keep randomly taking items out of the array until it is empty

```
import random

filename = open('new_file.txt')

lines = set( filename.readlines() )

while( len(lines) != 0 ):
    choice = random.choice(list(lines))
    print(choice)
    lines.remove(choice)
```

This answer may be helpful: [randomly selecting from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python)