# How to add 2 random numbers from a list together?

Tags: python, list

For example: 
`list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to get 2 random numbers from this list and add them together:

`3 + 2` for example.

Comment: Should it be possible to choose the same item twice? e.g. 2 +2

Comment: Yes that would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For unique selections** (sampling *without* replacement), you can make use of [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for selecting multiple random elements from the list and use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> from random import sample
>>> sum(sample(list1, 2))
7
```

A `ValueError` will be raised if you attempt to obtain a sample larger than your list (or more generally, population) size.

```
>>> sum(sample(list1, len(list1) + 1))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\random.py", line 315, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")
ValueError: Sample larger than population
```

---

**For non-unique selections** (sampling *with* replacement), a simple approach for small samples is just repeatedly calling [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) for whatever sample size you require.

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> sum(choice(list1) for _ in range(2))
6
```

Obviously when sampling with replacement, the sample size can be larger than the size of the population.

```
>>> sum(choice(list1) for _ in range(1000))
3527
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the solution, but what I'd like to tell you is that you wont go too far in programming by asking that kind of questions.

What you need to do before asking is to do some reflexion. for example, if I were you, I would have searched:

On google "`python get random number list`" > [How do I randomly select an item from a list using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python).

```
from random import choice

result = choice(list1) + choice(list1)
```

Good luck!

Comment: As this is a poor question, it could be usefull to provide a more general answer so it could maybe be usefull to futures reader. For example, how to sum to differrent randomly selected element? And what if I want to sum 3, 4 or N elements?

Comment: @bancan Yep! take a look to the update, it will help you :)

Comment: I was too specific while searching for an answer on google. Next time I'll try to be less specific. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if you want distinct elements, you can use:

```
import random

sum(random.sample(list1, 2))
```

Comment: Using numpy here is a little bit overkill, I think.

Comment: it adds conciseness to the problem if the two elements needs to be distinct.

Comment: just realized there is the same base python, but @Mitch asnwered previously I guess.

Answer (score 1):

For taking random numbers from the list you can use

```
import random
random.choice()
```

In your case use

```
import random
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sum=random.choice(list1)+random.choice(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function:

```
from random import choice
a=(random.choice(list1))
```

'a' will now be a random number from the list