# Numpy Random Choice not working for 2-dimentional list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I ran the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
a_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
np.random.choice(a_list, size=20, 
    replace=True)
```

expecting a result like this:

```
[[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

but what I got instead was the error message below:

```
 ValueError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-80-c11957aca587> in <module>()
    2 a_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
    3 np.random.choice(a_list, size=20, 
----> 4 replace=True)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

How do you randomly choose from a 2-dimensional list?

Comment: PLease fix the formatting in your question and also include the error message. You are saying "error message below", but there is no error message

Comment: You haven't included the error

Comment: oh, sorry! check it now I have included it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or can do `map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: random.choice(a_list),range(20))))
```

**Demo:**

```
import random
a_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
print(list(map(lambda x: random.choice(a_list),range(20))))
```

Output:

```
[[7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [10, 1, 2], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [10, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to use the indices:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]])
indices = np.arange(arr.shape[0])

output = arr[np.random.choice(indices, 20)]
```

Or, even shorter (based on hpaulj's comment):

```
output = arr[np.random.choice(arr.shape[0],20)]
```

Comment: A shorter way to generate the indices.

Comment: @hpaulj oops, misunderstood the suggestion. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy doesn't know if you want to extract a random row or a random cell from the matrix. That's why it only works with 1-D data.

You could use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
>>> import random
>>> a_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
>>> [random.choice(a_list) for _ in range(20)]
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

With Python 3.6 or newer, you can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) directly:

```
>>> random.choices(a_list, k=20)
[[10, 1, 2], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [10, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2], [10, 1, 2], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If you really want to use a numpy array, you'll have to convert your list of lists to a [1-D array of objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665118/6419007)

Answer (score 1):

## Sampling with replacement

#### Use `random.choices`

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]])
samples = random.choices(x, k=20)
```

## Sampling without replacement

#### Use `random.sample`

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]])
samples = random.sample(x.tolist(), k=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively,
use random to generate indices; then slice from the array. works on any dimention

```
n_sample = 10 #sample count
a_list [np.random.randint(0,a_list.shape[0], n_sample )]
```