# Python Function requesting input doesn't execute if statement - no error shown

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, user-input

I thoroughly searched for an answer to my question but couldn't find anything that would explain my results. I truly hope that anyone of you can point me in the right direction.

---

At the moment I am trying to program a text-based adventure game using Python 3 in order to better understand the language.

While doing so I created a function that should ask the **user** for **input** and **print a specific statement** depending on the users input. **In case** the **users input** is **invalid** the function should then **keep asking for input** until it is valid.

**Unfortunately the function only seems to keep asking for input, without ever executing the if/elif statements within the function. Due to no errors being shown I am currently at a loss as to why this is the case...**

---

```
print("If You want to start the game, please enter 'start'." + "\n" +              
      "Otherwise please enter 'quit' in order to quit the game.")

startGame = True


def StartGame_int(answer):
    if answer.lower() == "start":
        startGame = False
        return "Welcome to Vahlderia!"
    elif answer.lower() == "quit":
        startGame = False
        return "Thank You for playing Vahlderia!" + "\n" + "You can now close
                the window."
    else:
        return "Please enter either 'r' to start or 'q' to quit the game."

def StartGame(): 
    answ = input("- ")
    StartGame_int(answ)


while startGame == True:
    StartGame()
```

Comment: Your program asks the user to input either `r` or `q` but checks for `start` or `quit`, are you sure that's the behavior you want?

Comment: Also, you should put `global startGame` at the start of each function that you expect will change that value from `True` to `False`

Comment: you are using `return`, not `print`, the if statements do their job

Answer (score 2):

You fell into the scoping trap: you are creating a new variable `startGame` inside the function that is discarded after you leave it. You would instead need to modify the global one:

```
def StartGame_int(answer):
    global startGame   # you need to specify that you want to modify the global var
                       # not create a same-named var in this scope
    # rest of your code
```

This other SO questions might be of interest:

- [Python scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)
- [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)
- [Use of global keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

and my all time favorite:

- [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) so you enable yourself to debug your own code.

The last one will help you figure out why your texts that you *return* are not *print*ed and why the `if` does not work on `'r'` or `'q'` and whatever other problems you stumble into. It will also show you that your `if` are indeed executed ;o)

---

Other great things to read for your text adventure to avoid other beginner traps:

- [How to copy or clone a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)
- [How to parse a string to float or int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)
- [How to randomly select an item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)