# Unsure how to select one random output from this list in python

Tags: python, list, telegram-bot, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to select one random update.message from that list when the music funtion is called. I assume I should store all the links outside of the update.message so it doesnt send all 3 at the call of music

```
def music(bot, update):

    update.message.reply_text("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XErrOJGzKv8")
    update.message.reply_text("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ")
    update.message.reply_text("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmHg6BP5D8g")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
import random
foo=['link1','link2','link3']
random_link=random.choice(foo)
#call your function here using random_link
```

refer this question too [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

random is great at choosing something random.

```
import random
playlist = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XErrOJGzKv8','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmHg6BP5D8g']

def music(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(random.choice(playlist)) # random.choice() chooses a random item from a list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
import random

def music (bot, update):

    list_of_urls = ["www.your-urls.com", "www.your-urls2.com"]
    random_url = random.choice(list_of_urls)

    update.message.reply_text(random_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: store your values in a list.

Second step: just use `random.choice()`

```
import random

my_links = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XErrOJGzKv8",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmHg6BP5D8g"
]


def music(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(random.choice(my_links))
```