# generate random number that excludes one number from the range python

Tags: python, random, python-2.x

I am generating a number from the range of 1 to 10 but would like to exclude the number `2` from that range i have no idea how to go about doing this.

This is what i have so far.

**python file**

```
move =  random.randint(1, 10)
```

So to round of: I want to generate numbers between `1 to 10` and exclude number `2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```
move =  random.choice([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: Olivier's answer is probably better for this *specific* question but won't scale well if the rules are complex (like all primes less than a hundred). In that case, `choice` is the better , well choice, I guess :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a random value from 1 to 9 instead and shift it by one if it is bigger or equal to 2.

```
value =  random.randint(1, 9)

move = value if value < 2 else value + 1
```

Mathematically, you want to select a random element in a set of 9 elements. All you need to do is to identify the element 3 with 2, 4 with 3 and so on. In probability, this is what we call a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).

> A random variable is defined as a function that maps the outcomes of
>   unpredictable processes to numerical quantities.

This strategy of using a mapping is especially useful when your set is big and generating it would be costly, but the mapping rule is fairly simple.

**Improvement**:

It was pointed out by [U9-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773669/5079316) that in this case the mapping can be made slightly more efficient. It suffices to map 2 to 10.

```
value =  random.randint(1, 9)

move = value if value != 2 else 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do another way of conditioning like Olivier's answer:

```
value =  random.randint(1, 9)
move = 10 if move==2 else move
```

Then `move` will never be `2` again.

Comment: Your distribution is not uniform if you do that. 3 is more likely to be generated than any other number. See my answer.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Now?

Comment: Yes it works, I did not think of doing it like this, well done

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Happy it works :-), :D, , i voted for yours earlier already.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious and easy interpretable path would be to exclude the `2` by a `while-loop` and just drawing numbers, using the function you mentioned, until the `2` gets not picked. This is yet highly inefficient but a work-around you can reach with basic programming concepts.

The more direct way would be to define your list more precisely, meaning without the `2` and making use of the `random.choice` function:

```
import random
print(random.choice([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude number 2 using "while"

```
move =  random.randint(1, 10)

while move == 2:
    move = random.randint(1, 10)
```

This code will generate random number until it won't be "2"

Comment: While this works, there is always a small chance that it takes a very long time to generate your number.