# How to get randomly 20 elements from np.array and save it to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have DataFrame from 1 to 80 numbers how can i get randomly 20 elements and save result to another DataFrame? I cant save every list like a row. Its saving elements like a columns. In the future i want to try predict every radom elements with sklearn

```
   a = np.arange(1,81).reshape(8,10)
   pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I must to get 20 unique numbers and write it one row. For example in python:

```
      from random import sample          
      for x in range(1,20):
          i=sample(range(1,81), k=20)
          i.sort()
          print(x,'-',i)`
```

It return as list [1,3,5,8,34,45,12,76,45...] 20 elements and i want its look like :

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 20
0 1 5 10 14 20 55 67 34 ......     20 elements
1
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`df.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to get samples of data frm a dataframe:

```
a = np.arange(1,81).reshape(8,10)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df1= df.sample(frac=.25)
>>df1

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
5   51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
3   31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

For a random permutation [`np.random.permutation()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
df.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df))].head(2)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
6   61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
1   11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
```

**EDIT** : To get 20 elements in a list use:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.sample(frac=.25).values))
#[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

`frac=.25` means `25%` of the data, since you have used `80` elements `25%` gives you `20` elements, you can adjust the fraction depending on you many elements you have and how many you want.

**EDIT1:** Further to your edit in the question: `print(df.values)` gives you an array:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40]
 [41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]
 [51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60]
 [61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70]
 [71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]]
```

You would require to shuffle this array using [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) , in this case , do it on `df.T.values` since you also want to shuffle columns:

```
np.random.shuffle(df.T.values)
```

Then do a reshape:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(4,20)))

>>df1


    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   4   3   10  2   8   7   1   5   6   9   14  13  20  12  18  17  11  15  16  19
1   24  23  30  22  28  27  21  25  26  29  34  33  40  32  38  37  31  35  36  39
2   44  43  50  42  48  47  41  45  46  49  54  53  60  52  58  57  51  55  56  59
3   64  63  70  62  68  67  61  65  66  69  74  73  80  72  78  77  71  75  76  79
```

Comment: I want 20 unique element not sequence. For example:1,5,2,7,43,67,54,34,76,80,45,20,19,44,62 .. And its given me 10 columns i want get each 20 random number write in one row. It will be 10 columns i need 20 columns one row

Comment: @SoloMatador : please check EDIT and EDIT1 , think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot brah)) I thought i cant firstly explain correctly))

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way using existing stackoverflow answers:

1- flatten the array so it looks more like a list, will allow you to deal with only one index instead of dealing with two array indexes

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

```
aflat = a.flatten()
```

2- Choose random items from the flattened array any of the answers here

[How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

3- With the selected data, build your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and **you can specify exact rows** you want from the sample:

```
In [263]: a = np.arange(1,81).reshape(8,10)
In [265]: b = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [268]: b.iloc[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 5, False)]
Out[268]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
5  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
7  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
3  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
1  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
4  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
```

You can change `5` to `20` for your purpose. You need not worry about the percentile.

Comment: This is same too i want to get 20 unique elements and write in one row: For example like this 

               `from random import sample
               for x in range(1,20):
               i=sample(range(1,81), k=20)
               i.sort()
              print(x,'-',i)`