# Why is random.random() not secure in Python?

Tags: python, security, random, mersenne-twister

I came across this question on Stack overflow:
[How to randomly selection item from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)
and they mentioned that it is not suitable for cryptographic/security purposes.

So, I found this page in the official documentation: [random - Generate pseudorandom numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

It mentions that they use a Mersenne twister to generate random numbers.

Isn't Mersenne twister supposed to be a pretty decent random generator (at least that's what I was told in class)? So why can you not use it for security purposes?

Comment: You shouldn't handle security yourself (especially on a programming language you can introspect to find the seed :o)

Comment: But isn't the seed for the random generator randomly generated using the OS library (if it exists) or the system clock? Even if that was not the case, how would using the security library (that they suggest), get over that?

Comment: The intent of the `random` module is to provide usable random numbers for general purposes. But if you start using those random numbers for encryption then there may be someone prepared to invest effort in cracking your encryption, which is something that `random` is not designed to withstand. In that case, use the `secrets` module instead. See PEP 506 for the reasons why you should do this.

Comment: That's not my point, you could get the seed (introspection), and once you have it, you can predict all future numbers. Which is pretty bad in terms of security.

Comment: Using a "pretty decent random generator" for security purposes is really not on. Very easily hackable by determined attackers. Good security is very, very hard, so I agree with @BenoîtPilatte, don't try to handle it yourself.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense! Thanks a lot for your comments! Just as a side note, I wasn't trying to write my own security, I was just confused...

Comment: @Benoît P But all pseudo random number generators have a seed value. Even ones from respected cryptographic libraries have a seed value and are not based on True Random Number Generators. So what makes Random so much worse than then?

Comment: @AndrewS The applicable concept is [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability), from systems theory — can the system state be inferred in finite time from a sequence of observations. For MT the answer is yes, it can. Non-observable PRNGs exist, but are much more computationally costly than MT. They’re generally avoided for Monte Carlo computation where you care about speed and statistical properties but aren’t concerned about hiding the internal state.

Comment: PJS great answer, that is what was missing here and in a lot of other responses to similar questions across the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mersenne twister does a decent job of mimicking statistical properties(*) of randomness, but it is a deterministic algorithm.  If two copies are set to the same state, they will produce identical results in synchronization.  That means that for crypto/security applications your security is shot if an attacker can determine your initial state.  I've read that for MT this can be done by knowledgeable people after six hundred and some sequential observations.

Bottom line - use it for Monte Carlo sampling or stochastic models, but not for crypto.

(*) - Actually, [Pierre L'Ecuyer](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elecuyer/papers.html), who is considered one of the foremost researchers on pseudo-random number generation, is not a fan of MT even for Monte Carlo usage.  He has shown that while the full cycle is uniformly distributed, zeros in the the internal state tend to be persistent and the generator can get "stuck" for sizeable sub-periods in non-uniform subsequences.  He collaborated with the creator of Mersenne Twister to fix these issues in the [WELL generator](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Epanneton/WELLRNG.html).

Comment: Its kind of a red herring to say that pseudo random number generators should not be used for security purposes when some cryptographic processes such as the stream cipher depends on a deterministic pseudo random number generator with the seed as a key.

Comment: @AndrewS This post was specifically about MT. Not a red herring, MT is explicitly disrecommended for crypto use. I’d bet good money that NSA would be thrilled if you were to use it.

Comment: Yeah I guess being deterministic is not enough, if an attacker could find the sequence some how predicable. I was focused too much on that  "but not for crypto", when I'd been spending the afternoon messing with pseudo random number generators, and did not consider the predictability weakness owing to the internal states of MT sometimes not resulting in ideal randomness.