# How to select random choice after the script execution?

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate the telegram messaging platform and to send a reply, script must auto select a random reply from the array I provided.
Though the script is selecting randomly from the array it keep on sending the same reply. All I would like to see is a different selection each time.

I have already tried looking at [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list) 
and it seems this doesn't fit my need.

```
#content of the automatic reply
msg = ['hello','Hmmmm','what','alright','Done']
message = random.choice(msg)
```

[img] https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSA5G.jpg [/img]

When the user sends a message script must return a message from the provided array each at a time in a random manner. I am newbie to python and I appreciate any assistance here.

Comment: I tried the above snippet on a python shell, and it seems to choose different items from the list. I expect the issue to be somewhere else.

Comment: I double on the snippet working, it does print random selections from msg.

Comment: We are assigning a message to variable here as you see the code above does that. I think there is no where we can do modifications.

Comment: I suspect you've seeded the random number generator manually.

Comment: Agree it prints random message each time you run the script. Here I ran the script only once and it waits for messages. as a new message arrives it replies with the one it stored.

Comment: it's work check out integration @Maverick

Answer (score 0):

How many times did you tried? It should work:

```
import random

i=0
while i < 20:
    message = random.choice(msg)
    print(message)
    i+=1
```

output:

```
alright
what
what
alright
Done
what
hello
what
alright
alright
Hmmmm
Hmmmm
Hmmmm
hello
Hmmmm
Hmmmm
hello
hello
Hmmmm
hello
```

If otherwise what you want to is to have a different choice each time, you could try to remember last choice and avoid using it:

```
import random

msg = ['hello','Hmmmm','what','alright','Done']
message = random.choice(msg)
last_choice = message
i = 0
while i < 20:
  new_list = [ m for m in msg if m != last_choice ]
  message = random.choice(new_list)
  print(message)
  last_choice = message
  i+=1
```