# Printing random data from list into file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists

```
x = ["1", "2", "3"]

y = ["4", "5", "6"]

z = ["7", "8", "9"]
```

I need to write into a file with a random from x, y, and z on to a new line each time.

```
Keyword = input("Directory to list")

with open(Keyword) as f: 
        content = f.readlines()

    content = [x.strip() for x in content]

    with open("test.txt") as w:
        w.write(PageFormat + )
```

Output should look like this:

```
2 // 6 // 8

3 // 4 // 9

1 // 5 // 9

2 // 5 // 9

1 // 4 // 7
```

("/" included)

Comment: You can use `random.choice(x)` in order to select a random value from the list `x`.

Comment: You can refer [How to randomly select an item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:-**

```
import random


x = ["1", "2", "3"]

y = ["4", "5", "6"]

z = ["7", "8", "9"]


file = open("new.txt",'w')

for a in range(0, 10):
    file.write(x[random.randrange(0,3)] + " // " + y[random.randrange(0,3)] + " // " + z[random.randrange(0,3)] + "\n")

file.close()
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:-**

```
2 // 4 // 9
1 // 6 // 9
2 // 5 // 9
1 // 6 // 8
1 // 5 // 8
3 // 5 // 9
3 // 4 // 7
2 // 6 // 7
1 // 5 // 7
2 // 4 // 8
```

You can control the number of iterations by changing the second argument of `range()`. This program will write 10 lines into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice

x = ["1", "2", "3"]

y = ["4", "5", "6"]

z = ["7", "8", "9"]

with open("test.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(choice(x) + "//" + choice(y) + "//" + choice(z))
```