# How do I randomly choose a item/ variable from an external file such as a .txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that is able to randomly choose a name/ word from an external list such as .txt files however, I don't know how to import variables from an external list.

Thank You

Comment: atleast try something. Search how to read file first. Then serach how to select random element from list python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Comment: `random` module is the best bet here something like this`import random; random.choice([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: I do know how to select random but don't know how to select from an external file. Thank You for the support guys. I manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple.

```
import random

inp = open("path/to/your/file/file.txt")
lines=inp.read().split("\n")
nLines = len(lines)
index = int(random.random()*nLines)
inp.close()

randLine = lines[index]
print(randLine)
```

now depending on the format of your input file you might need to parse things a little differently but this is an example for just grabbing a random line of text from a file.

**Edit:** as `_mad` points out you can use `random.choice()`

```
import random

inp = open("path/to/your/file/file.txt")
lines=inp.read().split("\n")
inp.close()

randLine = random.choice(lines)
print(randLine)
```

Comment: Please please refrain from answering questions that produce zero efforts into solving the problem by OP.

Comment: It's my time to waste : /