# How to create a small random list from a larger list with Python

Tags: python

I want to create a list containing three items randomly chosen from a list of many items. This is how I have done it, but I feel like there is probably a more efficient (zen) way to do it with python.

```
import random

words = ['bacon', 'gorilla', 'phone', 'hamburger', 'mother']

small_list = []

while len(small_list) < 4:
    word = random.choice(words)
    if word not in small_list:
        small_list.append(word)
```

Expected output would be something like:

```
small_list = ['phone', 'bacon', 'mother']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
import random

words = ['bacon', 'gorilla', 'phone', 'hamburger', 'mother']
small_list = random.sample(words, k=3)

print(small_list)
# ['mother', 'bacon', 'phone']
```

Comment: Great! Exactly the python zen I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30488952/7431860), you can use `random.sample()` to pick a set amount of data.

```py
small_list = random.sample(words, 4)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GroundedSuperiorQuarks)