# How to select a result at random when looping through a list with two matches

Tags: python

I am looping through a list of tuples and I want to add a conditional so that if the condition has multiple successes only one of them is chosen with an equal percentage of chance.

```
In [1]:
junctions = ([1,2], [1,3], [2,3])
roads = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
for a, b in junctions:
  if a == 1:
    print(roads[b])
```

```
Out [1]:
c
d
```

In this example, I would want it to return either c or d with a 50% chance. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to randomly select items *while looping*, or just select all items and *then* randomly reduce items with the same key?

Comment: "Do you want to randomly select items while looping, or just select all items and then randomly reduce items with the same key?"

I think it makes more sense to randomly select them while looping? 

I am going to use the result of this loop to select from another list. 

i.e. instead of print[b] I would be using newlist[b] = "New Value"

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Is your data restricted/structured in any way to make an early decision while looping? E.g. is it sorted by the primary key/condition, is the number of successes known ahead of time? Do you have more than one condition? Is your data reasonably small to fit in memory?

Comment: @ScientistStats Why would it make more sense to do it while looping? It's possible and fairly easy, but selecting them afterwards is *trivial*.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? There are plenty of resources on how to select items from a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
from random import choice

possibilities = []
junctions = ([1,2], [1,3], [2,3])
roads = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
for a, b in junctions:
  if a == 1:
     possibilities.append(roads[b])

print(choice(possibilities))
```

Comment: (Not asked, but the loop can be avoided with a plain list comprehension doing exactly the same thing: `possibilities = [roads[b] for a,b in junctions if a==1]`)

Comment: @usr2564301 i usually try to make the smallest possible change to the OP code, makes it easier to understand the answer and figure out why the changes were necessary.

Comment: Yep `:)` That's why I only commented, it'd not add anything new to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could append these to a new list, and use random.randint() to pick from the size of the new list

```
import random
sampleList = []
x = random.randint(0,len(sampleList))
print(sampleList[x])
```

Comment: The ``random`` module already provides means to pick from a list. There is no need to wrongly reimplement it (your version may pick an index one after the end of the list).