# Randomly choose a file inside a folder using Hypothesis

Tags: python, testing, python-hypothesis

I want to add tests using the Hypothesis library (already use in the software for testing). 
For these tests, I have to use a set of txt files contained in a folder. 
I need to randomly choose one of these files each time I run my tests.
How to do that using Hypothesis?

**edit**
Here basically how it would look like, to comply the templates of already existing tests.

```
@given(doc=)
def mytest(doc):

    # assert some stuff according to doc
    assert some_stuff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, because I want this to be done  using Hypthesis

Comment: Why do you need Hypothesis for your very simple case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Static case

If files list is assumed to be "frozen" (no files will be deleted/added) then we can use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) + [`hypohtesis.strategies.sampled_from`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.sampled_from) like

```py
import os

from hypothesis import strategies

directory_path = 'path/to/directory/with/txt/files'
txt_files_names = strategies.sampled_from(sorted(os.listdir(directory_path)))
```

or if we need full paths

```py
from functools import partial
...
txt_files_paths = (strategies.sampled_from(sorted(os.listdir(directory_path)))
                   .map(partial(os.path.join, directory_path)))
```

or if the directory may have files of different extensions and we need only *.txt* ones we can use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

```py
import glob
...
txt_files_paths = strategies.sampled_from(sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, '*.txt'))))
```

## Dynamic case

If directory contents may change and we want to make directory scan on each data generation attempt it can be done like

```py
dynamic_txt_files_names = (strategies.builds(os.listdir,
                                             strategies.just(directory_path))
                           .map(sorted)
                           .flatmap(strategies.sampled_from))
```

or with full paths

```py
dynamic_txt_files_paths = (strategies.builds(os.listdir,
                                             strategies.just(directory_path))
                           .map(sorted)
                           .flatmap(strategies.sampled_from)
                           .map(partial(os.path.join, directory_path)))
```

or with `glob.glob`

```py
dynamic_txt_files_paths = (strategies.builds(glob.glob,
                                             strategies.just(os.path.join(
                                                     directory_path,
                                                     '*.txt')))
                           .map(sorted)
                           .flatmap(strategies.sampled_from))
```

## Edit

- Added `sorted` following [comment by @Zac Hatfield-Dodds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259151/randomly-choose-a-file-inside-a-folder-using-hypothesis/60262557#comment106625794_60262557).

Comment: You should put a `.map(sorted)` before the flatmap to ensure that examples are reproducible - not all operating systems or file systems guarantee stable iteration order, and that would break replay.

Comment: the `sorted` specifically needs to be *before* `sampled_from` - as written you're not stabilising iteration order, you're converting a string to a sorted list of characters!

Comment: @ZacHatfield-Dodds: you are right, my mistake, tested only "static" case, should be fixed now