# How to fetch a random image link from a site in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping I don't know much about it. I have made a bit of program which fetches a random image link from a website , But I get a list of links while doing so I am not getting a single link

HERE'S MY CODE

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
import random


requester = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=Request("https://image.com",headers=requester)
u =urlopen(req)


soup = BeautifulSoup(u.read(), features="lxml")



links = soup.find_all('a')

images =[]
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))
    img=random.choice(images)
    
    print(img)
```

HERE'S THE OUTPUT

```
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.LongIsland_EN-US4283514207_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.BeaverDam_EN-US4184266799_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.PicoIsland_EN-US3959411167_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.LongIsland_EN-US4283514207_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.FinancialTowers_EN-US3881212547_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.LongIsland_EN-US4283514207_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.BeaverDam_EN-US4184266799_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.PicoIsland_EN-US3959411167_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.BeaverDam_EN-US4184266799_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.LongIsland_EN-US4283514207_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.LongIsland_EN-US4283514207_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.FinancialTowers_EN-US3881212547_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.PRNLCavern_EN-US7693319589_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.FinancialTowers_EN-US3881212547_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.BeaverDam_EN-US4184266799_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.PicoIsland_EN-US3959411167_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.FinancialTowers_EN-US3881212547_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
```

I only want a single link from the above list also link should be randomize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Comment: The problem is that I want only one link I also used random.choice() but I am unable to think why a list of link appears

Comment: Did you mean for your last two lines of code to be indented? It seems like they shouldn't be.

Comment: replace the final for loop with: `print(random.choice(soup.findAll('img')))`

Comment: or just `print(random.choice(images))`

Comment: Just unindent your last two lines of code, you're running your choice making in for loop which is not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `img=random.choice(images)` out of the for loop.

```
images =[]
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

img=random.choice(images)    
print(img)
```

Comment: What was the reason for the above output

Comment: It is because you are getting random URL(`img=random.choice(images)`) in for loop and you are printing(`print(img)`) in for loop.

Comment: Thanks for telling me