# How to choose a random element from a list and then find its index in the list?

Tags: python

I have a list of names and using `random.choice()`, I am able to get a random element from the list. Now I am trying to figure out at what index that given element sits in the list. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

x = ['Jess','Jack','Mary','Sophia','Karen','Addison','Joseph','Eric','Ilona','Jason']
y = random.choice(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: x.index(y) will give you the index.

Comment: does the list contain duplicates?

Comment: It does not but would it matter?

Comment: Yes it will matter. `index` only returns the first occurrence in the list.

Comment: list.index(element, start,end) is the command. So if you dont provide start or end, then it will find the first occurrence. If there are duplicates, it won't find the next one unless you specify the start position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list) See this answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373205/7851470

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
x.index(y)
```

This will return the **first index** in the list where it finds a match. However, this will not return the correct index if you have duplicates in your list.

---

A better way to handle this, in the case you have duplicates would be to randomise the index instead of the value. As you will always store the correct index you're referencing and not the first occurance.

```
y = random.randint(0, len(x))
#3

x[y]

#Sophia
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```py
import random

x = ['Jess','Jack','Mary','Sophia','Karen','Addison','Joseph','Eric','Ilona','Jason']
i = random.randrange(len(x))

print(i, x[i])
```

Example output:

> 7 Eric

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in 2 ways.

### Method 1

1. Find the length of the list (n) and then choose a random integer from 0-n as K.
2. Return the element in the list at kth index and the index k

```
import random
x = ['Jess','Jack','Mary','Sophia','Karen','Addison','Joseph','Eric','Ilona','Jason']
k = random.randrange(len(x)) # k is the random index
print(x[k], k) # x[k] will be the random element
```

### Method 2

Pick the random element using `random.choice` and then use `list.index` to find the index

```
value= random.choice(x)
index= x.index(value)
```

***Note 1***: *This doesn't work well when **duplicate elements** are present in the list*

Most preferred way would be **Method 1**

---

You can also use random.choice to get the index

```
index = random.choice(range(len(x)))
value = x[index]
```

But this is a bit slow compared to `random.randange`

Answer (score 0):

You can give `y = x.index(random.choice(x))`  This will assign the index to `y`

Comment: how your answer is different from @PacketLoss

Comment: I guess we both responded at the same time