# How to add a number outside of the range that could be randomly selected

Tags: python-3.x, random

```
sides=random.randrange(3,10)
```

I'd like to add 360 to the numbers that could be randomly selected.

I want a random number from the following numbers:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 360]
```

I know how to get a random number from 3 to 10, but I don't know how to make `360` a possible choice too.

Comment: Do you want 3-360 or 3-10 + 360 so 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,360?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `random.choice`:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([*range(3, 11), 365])
5
>>>
```