# Create a generator to yield random number from a list

Tags: python, random, generator

I would like to create a generator which spits out a random number from a pre-specified list.  Something like this:

```
x = random_select([1,2,3])
next(x) # 1
next(x) # 3
next(x) # 3
next(x) # 2
# and so on
```

How can I do so?

---

Here's my motivation.  I know I can use `random.choice` to [select a value randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306417/13386979).  My issue is that in my program, I sometimes want to randomly select items from a given list, while other times I want to cycle over the elements (a variable number of times for either option).  I do the latter with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

y = itertools.cycle([1,2,3])
next(y) # 1
next(y) # 2
next(y) # 3
next(y) # 1
# and so on
```

I would like to create a generator object which can yield the values of a list randomly instead of in a cycle, so that I can still get out all the values I need with `next` and not have to specify when to use `random.choice` to retrieve values.  E.g. currently I do:

```
import itertools
import random

l = [1,2,3]
select = 'random'
output = []
cycle = itertools.cycle(l) # could conditionally build this generator

for i in range(10):
    if select == 'random':
        output.append(random.choice(l))
    elif select == 'cycle':
        output.append(next(cycle))
```

I find this logic clunky, and if I add more selection options it might get worse.  I would like to do something like:

```
l = [1,2,3]
select = 'cycle'
options = {'cycle':itertools.cycle, 'random':random_select}
g = options[select](l)

output = [next(g) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create such a generator like so:

```
import random

def random_select(l):
    while True:
        yield random.choice(l)

g = random_select([1,2,3])
```

This will infinitely yield random choices from `l`, and works with the final example above.