# How to print a string at random from a given choices of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have given three strings 'aaa','bbb','ccc' and i want to print any one of these at random, how to do it?

Comment: `import random; choices = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']; print(random.choice(choices))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

Use random

```
import random
print(random.choice(['aaa','bbb','ccc']))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice

strings = ['aa','bb','cc']
print(choice(strings))
```

Answer (score -1):

Given you have your strings in an array you can get the random integer in range (between 1 and 3 in your case) using `random.randint`:

```
import random
a=['aaa','bbb','ccc']
rnd=random.randint(1,3)
print(a[rnd])
```

Answer (score -1):

Build a list with all the String options. Next generate a random whole number in the range between 0 and the highest index of the list. This number becomes the index for the selected string.

`random()` gives you a random float value between 0 and 1.

something like this should work

```
>>> from random import random
>>> options = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
>>> selected_idx = int(random() * len(options))
>>> options[selected_idx]
'bbb'
```