# How can I send a random file out of a folder with my Discord bot?

Tags: python-3.x, image, discord.py

I want my bot to send random images from a locally created folder, for this I tried the following code:

```py
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(random.choice(r "F:\Discordbot\hug")))
```

This one didn't really work though. Where is the error or how can I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you face any errors? What is the traceback? You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Comment: @stijndcl This is not really what he is asking/looking for. He wants to select random items out of a folder, not list.

Comment: @Dominik ``os.listdir`` returns a ``list``, so looking up how to get files in a folder (which should be the first search result) & combining that with the post I linked _is_ what he's looking for. If he's trying to get things out of a folder, he's also trying to get things out of a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the path a little differently and then send it accordingly.

***Here is an example:***

```py
import random
import os

@client.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    path = random.choice(os.listdir('Full Path/'))
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File("Full Path/"+path))
```

- Make sure you copy the whole path
- Use `/` instead of `\`
- Add a `/` at the end of the folder path
- import `os` and `random`