# Pick a random choice from a list in Python without repeating

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list lets say `x = [8,6,4,1]` I want to pick a random element from this list in Python but each time picking this item shouldn't be the same item picked previously. So I don't want a repetition

How can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplication. Answers from the below post can clearly help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list

Comment: I understood your question in a way different from what other people did. You might want to [edit] your question to clarify it. Consider [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random` package

```py
import random

x = [8,6,4,1]
random.shuffle(x)

for number in x:
    print(number)
```

One note here: `shuffle` doesn't return anything (well, `None` actually). Instead of returning a new list, it *mutates* it. That means that you're unable to use it into a loop declaration

```py
for number in random.shuffle(x):  # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `randrange` to generate a random index, use a range smaller by 1, because there is one forbidden index. To convert the output of `randrange` to the needed range (with one number removed), conditionally add 1 to the number.

```
def random_choice_without_repetition(list x, int forbidden_index):
    index = random.randrange(len(list) - 1)
    if index >= forbidden_index:
        index += 1
    return index
```

This code returns an index instead of the element itself, because it wants to receive the forbidden index. You might want to adapt it to your use case to make it more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just shuffling the list and picking the first item until list length > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
x = [8,6,4,1]
y = range(len(x))
random.shuffle(y)
```

Now each time you want to pick a random element do:

```
print(x[y.pop()])
```