# How do I randomly select between two strings with the `or` operator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have problems with the or operator. I'm just starting out with Python. I should print in the textbox either A or B. Can't. Problem is, only A. B does not print. How can I do? Thank you

```
A = f"{name} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"
B = f"Che sale a"
        
text.insert(tk.END, A or B)
```

Comment: You want it to insert random?

Comment: Are you wanting randomness? It will only print `B` is `A` is an empty string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: @Samathingamajig I think so. Because the link also talks about secure_random = random.SystemRandom()? What does it mean?

Comment: It seems to be a better random number generator, but that's not needed for something as simple as this (probably is slower & more system demanding). Learn more here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html#module-secrets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to randomly select to display `A` or `B`. You can do this with the pre-installed `random` module. `random.choice` takes in a list and randomly returns one element from that list, which is the desired behavior.

```py
import random

A = f"{name} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"
B = f"Che sale a"
        
text.insert(tk.END, random.choice([A, B]))
```

If you would like to use a more secure version of `random.choice`, you can do so with the pre-installed [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html#module-secrets)

```py
import secrets

A = f"{name} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"
B = f"Che sale a"
        
text.insert(tk.END, secrets.choice([A, B]))
```

Comment: @Samanthingamajic perfect. thank you. I didn't know about the random module

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `if` statement to decide in what condition A or B should be printed.
Or is actually used with booleans. If either of the booleans are true, `or` will return true.

Comment: Not exactly. `or`, the python version of `||` actually returns the first truthy value. Look here for an example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zqNl4LfeK8KeS4cf (source code for future readers: `print("" or "Hello, World"); print(5 or 6); print(0 or 6); print(False or None); print(None or "Hello")`)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that it could also be used like that.. Thanks for the info!