# How i can get random object from list in Python

Tags: python

I have build a list which contains href from website and i wanna randomly select one of this link, how can i do that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import requests
import re
import random

url = "https://www.formula1.com/en/latest.html"
articles = []
respone = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(respone,'lxml')

def getItems():
       for a in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/latest/article.")}):
           articles = a['href']
           x = random.choice(articles)
           print(x)
```

That code work, but selecting only random index from all of the objects

Comment: For those of use unfamiliar with beautiful soup, What, exactly, is `a['href']`? can you `print(repr(a['href'])`? I suspect it is a *string* not a list.

Comment: Probably, `articles` is a `str`. Try `random.choice(articles.split())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to the answer. You just need to do this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import requests
import re
import random

url = "https://www.formula1.com/en/latest.html"
articles = []
respone = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(respone,'lxml')

def getItems():
       for a in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("/en/latest/article.")}):
           articles.append(a['href'])
       x = random.choice(articles)
       print(x)

getItems()
```

The changes are:

- We add each article to the `articles` array.
- The random choice is now done after the loop, rather than inside the loop.

Comment: If this will be used for anything where someone might try to guess, use `secrets.choice(articles)` rather than `random.choice(articles)`?