# Function for random integer of two numbers and not between to numbers

Tags: python, random

Maybe very basic question but is there a random function that gives me the integers eg. 1 or 6.

I don't mean random.randint(1, 6). I want either 1 or 6, no numbers in between.

Comment: Choose a random value of 0 or 1 and select the number you want based on the two possible outcomes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

random.choice((1, 6))
```

This will return a random selection from the tuple you pass in.  Since the tuple only contains the numbers 1 and 6, those are the only possible outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
random.randint(0, 1) * 5 + 1
```

**How it works:**

First, you choose a number between 0 or 1 randomly. Second, you multiply it by 5 which will result to either 0 or 5. At last you add 1 which is going to change (0 or 5) to (1 or 6).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript version of the expression that randomly gives you either 1 or 6:

```
1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 5
```