# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str (Renaming folders)

Tags: python

```
import os
import random

path = os.getcwd()

directory_list = os.listdir(path)

for filename in directory_list:
    src = filename
    words = ('Random Word', 'Random Word 2', 'Random Word 3')
    random_index = random.choice(words)
    dst = filename[0: + filename.find('-'), words[random_index]]
    os.rename(src, dst)

print("File renamed!")
```

In the above, I am trying to rename folders in a directory, removing everything after the symbol - and appending words to the end.

The first part worked until I tried to add the random words, I now receive the error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What is the full error?  What line of code is it referring to?

Comment: Can you explain this line? `dst = filename[0: + filename.find('-'), words[random_index]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, `random.choice` returns a string and not an index.

So you need to rewrite you code as follows:

```
    words = ('Random Word', 'Random Word 2', 'Random Word 3')
    random_wrd = random.choice(words)
    dst = filename.split('-')[0] + random_wrd
```

Also I would initialize `words` outside of the for loop.
You might also want to use `random.seed()` at the start, or the chosen sequence of words will be the same every time you launch the script.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made the changes, as well moved words outside of the loop, but I now get this:

dst = filename[0: + filename.find('-'), random_wrd]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Yes, you have some syntax issues in the `dst=...` line.
You probably meant `dst = filename[0:filename.find('-')] + random_wrd`.
I edited my answer with a probably better approach.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that, just one more question, how would I make sure to add a space between the first part + random word?

Comment: In python you can append strings with the `+` operator, so just `filename.split('-')[0] + ' '  + random_wrd`