# New list of not repeated elements

Tags: python, list

I want to create a function that take a lsit as argument, for example:

```
list = ['a','b','a','d','e','f','a','b','g','b']
```

and returns a specific number of list elements ( i chose the number) such that no number occurs twice. For example if i chose 3:

```
 new_list = ['a','b','d']
```

I tried the following:

```
def func(j, list):
    new_list=[]
    for i in list:
        while(len(new_list)<j):
            for k in new_list:
                if i != k:
                    new_list.append(i)
                    
                    return new_list
```

But the function went through infinite loop.

Comment: What is `letters`?

Comment: [Remove the duplicates in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists). Then [randomly select as many items as you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30488952/843953)

Comment: Please run the code you have posted here and make sure it actually runs and reproduces your problem [mre]

Comment: You need to remove your `list` variable. It is overriding the built-in list function

Comment: @ely66: Is there any specific ordering needed? It looks like you want it in order by first appearance in the original `list`, but you might also be selecting by first alphabetically, or you might allow random selection, or whatever.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I need them in the order of first appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func(j, mylist):
    # dedup, preserving order (dict is insertion-ordered as a language guarantee as of 3.7):
    deduped = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
    # Slice off all but the part you care about:
    return deduped[:j]
```

If performance for large inputs is a concern, that's suboptimal (it processes the whole input even if `j` unique elements are found in first `j` indices out of an input where `j` is much smaller than the input), so the more complicated solution can be used for maximum efficiency. First, copy [the `itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import filterfalse, islice  # At top of file, filterfalse for recipe, islice for your function

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

now wrap it [with `islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to only pull off as many elements as required and exiting immediately once you have them (without processing the rest of the input at all):

```
def func(j, mylist):  # Note: Renamed list argument to mylist to avoid shadowing built-in
    return list(islice(unique_everseen(mylist), j))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```py
lst = ['a','b','a','d','e','f','a','b','g','b']

j = 3

def func(j,list_):
    new_lst = []
    for a in list_:
        if a not in new_lst:
            new_lst.append(a)

    return new_lst[:j]

print(func(j,lst)) # ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

I don't know why someone does not post a [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique) solution

Here is memory efficient way(I think ).

```
import numpy as np
lst = ['a','b','a','d','e','f','a','b','g','b']

def func(j,list_):
    return np.unique(list_).tolist()[:j]

print(func(3,lst)) # ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: Your second approach was actually better. `a not in new_lst` is slow for large lists.

Comment: @ely66 you get that error because of what [OneCricketeer commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205596/new-list-of-not-repeated-elements#comment127573842_72205596). Don't shadow python builtins with your variables.

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a reserved word in python.

If order of the elements is not a concern then

```py
def func(j, user_list):
    return list(set(user_list))[:j]
```

Comment: this will work but with python is not guaranteed that the list will have the exact order you would expect

Answer (score 1):

it's bad practice to use "list" as variable name

you can solve the problem by just using the Counter lib in python

```
from collections import Counter
a=['a','b','a','d','e','f','a','b','g','b']

b = list(Counter(a))

print(b[:3])
```

so your function will be something like that

```
def unique_slice(list_in, elements):
    new_list = list(Counter(list_in))
    print("New list: {}".format(new_list))
    if int(elements) <= len(new_list):
            return new_list[:elements]
    return new_list
```

hope it solves your question

Comment: No need to import/use `Counter`; `dict.fromkeys(list_in)` will get the same effect, but without counting them (since you're not using the counts here anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you should not Shadow built-in name 'list'. Because that could lead to many issues. This is a simple problem where you should add to a new list and check if the element was already added.

The [:] operator in python lets you separate the list along an index.

```
>>>l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>l[:1]
[1]
>>>l[1:]
[2, 3, 4]
```

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'b']


def func(number, _list):
    out = []
    for a in _list:
        if a not in out:
            out.append(a)

    return out[:number]


print(func(4, lst))  # ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
```