# How to choose 3 random numbers from a pandas.series object?

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` object that looks like this:

```
6          7
8          9
18        19
35        36
42        43
```

I want to get a list of 3 randomly chosen numbers from this list. I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)  and tried

```
sampled_list = random.sample(df['ID'], 3)
```

with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df['ID'].sample(n = 3).tolist()`?

Comment: If I just google the question title, the first result is [pandas.Series.sample — pandas 1.4.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html). Please start with your own research in the future. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
df['ID'].sample(3).tolist()
```

Docs: [`Series.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
sampled_list = random.sample(list(df['ID']), 3)
```