# How a create a random string combination of postive, Negative, floats, Upper case, Lower case elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python seeking your help. I would like to create a string combination of **postive, Negative, floats, Upper case, Lower case elements**

Example: Like random combination.

```
As-1jP0.7M -->output
```

Explanation

```
A - caps A 
s- small S
-1 - Negative 1 
j- small j
0.7 - float 0.7
M- caps M
```

My ranges

```
Caps - A - Z
small- a -z
positive - 0 to 9
Negatives - -1 to -9
float - 0.1 to 0.9
```

I know I'm asking too much but by doing some basic researcg I got idea how to generate combination of `Alphanumeric` numbers like.

```
import random, string
x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
print(x)
```

This ok...But, I'm completely clueless how to add `Negative` & `float` types along with `alphanumerics`..Any suggestions how to achieve it. Like we have any some shorcuts like `string.floatdigits`? or `string.negatives`? I've searched for similar syntax but, But I 'havent found anything

Comment: Like `(-(string.digits))` ? for negatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate separate lists according to your ranges and use accordingly.

1. Generate separate lists according to your ranges
2. Merge them - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)
3. Generate random item n number of times & Join as str - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Code:

```
import string
import random

list_small=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
list_cap=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
list_dig = list(range(9,-10,-1)) #both postive & Neg
floats= [ round(x * 0.1, 1) for x in range(1, 10)]

#Merge list    
all_list = list_small + list_cap + list_dig +floats
s =''.join(str(x) for x in ([random.choice(all_list) for i in range(10)]))

print(s)
```

#output

```
ircZC-1bj0.7k
```

Comment: Thanks for the time & References you provided...Really helped!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random, string
x = ''.join(random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase) + 
                          list(string.ascii_lowercase) + 
                          ['0']+[ch+dig for dig in string.digits[1:] for ch in ['', '-', '0.'] ]) 
            for _ in range(10))
print(x)
```

Random output:`0.3z0.7Q0.52-9Ghe`

Another random output: `Op-7-1R0.8M7wz`

Comment: Let me try this thsnk you @mahdi